# Kafka connect spooldir Dynamic schema generator

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect

This is regarding kafka-connect-spooldir connector for CSV. I would like to know if there is a way to avoid hardcoding the schema and let the connector create schema dynamically? I have a lot of csv files to process say few hundreds GB per day sometimes a couple of tera bytes of csv. Sometimes some csv files have new columns and some are dropped.

I am able to successfully read the csv and write to elastic search, and I followed your post.https://www.confluent.io/blog/ksql-in-action-enriching-csv-events-with-data-from-rdbms-into-AWS/
So now I do not want to use value schema and key schema.

From the link https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-spooldir/connectors/csv_source_connector.html; I figured that schema.generation.enabled can be set to true.

here's my REST API call [ including my connector config]

```
$curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H  "Content-Type:application/json" http://xxx:000/connectors/ -d '{
"name":"csv1",
"config":{
"tasks.max":"1",
"connector.class":"com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.spooldir.SpoolDirCsvSourceConnector",
"input.file.pattern":"^.*csv$",
"halt.on.error":"false",
"topic":"order",
"schema.generation.enabled":"true",
"schema.generation.key.name":"orderschema",
"schema.generation.value.name":"orderdata",
"csv.first.row.as.header":"true",
"csv.null.field.indicator":"EMPTY_SEPARATORS",
"batch.size" : "5000",
   }
}
'
```

When I submit this, i get the following error. 
{
  "name": "order",
  "connector": {
    "state": "FAILED",
    "worker_id": "localhost:000",
    "trace": "org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: **More than one schema was found for the input pattern.\nSchema:** {\"name\":\"com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.model.Value\",\"type\":\"STRUCT\",\"isOptional\":false,\"fieldSchemas\":

Whats the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to parse all the data now. Trick was to process one file first [ any] and then just to check add randomly add another. It looks like that way, it updates the schema automagically. (like how Robin Moffatt calls it)
After that add all files to the folder, it process just fine. YAY!